# How to prove that the infinity norm of a matrix is the max of row sum?

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I know how to prove that the 1-norm of a matrix is the max of the column sum, but not sure how to prove that the inf-norm is the max of the row sum.

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: Hmm, I think I've seen this question here recently, right down to mentioning the 1-norm.  Did you ask it once already?

Comment: no i haven't. This is the first time.

Comment: Well, you need to prove that (a) the purported operator norm _is_ the norm of the image of some unit vector, and (b) that this is the largest possible norm for the image of a unit vector. Can you make any progress on either of those parts?

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Suppose that $x$ with entries $x_j$ satisfies $\|x\|_\infty = 1$.  Then the $j$th entry of $Mx$ is given by
$$
\sum_{k=1}^m M_{jk}x_k
$$
We note that
$$
\left|\sum_{k=1}^m M_{jk}x_k\right| \leq
\sum_{k=1}^m \left|M_{jk}x_k\right| \leq
\sum_{k=1}^m \left|M_{jk}\right| \|x\|_{\infty}
$$
Then, for any $j$, we can consider the vector $x$ whose entries are given by
$$
x_k = \frac{|M_{jk}|}{M_{jk}}
$$